# Homotopy theory based on an other space than the circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This question might seem philosohical. To me homotopy theory is based on two piece of information in the category of topological spaces : the circle $X = S^1$, and the reduced suspension functor $F = \Sigma$, then everything can be deduced from there : the homotopy groups functors are $[F^n X,-]$, CW-complexes are defined using homotopy quotient of spheres $F^n X$ etc. Is there a reason why no other homotopy theories are used, for example, for $X = RP^n$, or $X = K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ etc. Is is possible to have a homotopy theory also by changing the functor $F$ ? Or the only sane choice is the right adjoint to the mapping space functor $Map(X,-)$ ?

Comment: "everything can be deduced from there" is a hardcore exaggeration, even in the narrow context of homotopy itself (take for example: pointed vs free homotopy). Anyway you may want to read this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92206/what-properties-make-0-1-a-good-candidate-for-defining-fundamental-groups

Comment: Thank you, I meant, the main objects of homotopy theory (homotopy groups, weak homotopy equivalence, CW complexes etc) can be defined from spheres.